# Displayport Not Working Ubuntu 22.04/Intel HD 4000

Tags: video, hdmi, displayport

I am trying to connect my second monitor through DisplayPort. My first monitor is connected to HDMI port. The DisplayPort is not detected. I am new to Ubuntu.

The drivers installed.

```
lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display' 
 
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation IvyBridge GT2 [HD Graphics 4000] (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
```

Xrandr output:

```
Screen 0: minimum 16 x 16, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
XWAYLAND0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 480mm x 270mm
   1920x1080     59.96*+
   1440x1080     59.99  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1280x1024     59.89  
   1280x960      59.94  
   1152x864      59.96  
   1024x768      59.92  
   800x600       59.86  
   640x480       59.38  
   320x240       59.52  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x800      59.81  
   720x480       59.71  
   640x400       59.95  
   320x200       58.96  
   1600x900      59.95  
   1368x768      59.88  
   1280x720      59.86  
   1024x576      59.90  
   864x486       59.92  
   720x400       59.55  
   640x350       59.77
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Are you certain that your machine allows both the HDMI port and DisplayPort to be used at the same time? Some machines offer only one at a time 

Comment: I checked the Gigabyte GA-Z77X-UD4H user's manual says the motherboard supports dual monitor configuration in operating environment only. Also, I tried connecting the monitor with only Displayport and no HDMI but it still did not work. Do I have to find a specific Displayport cable? I used Amazon Basic's Displayport to HDMI cable. I think my Displayport type is Dp-1.1.

Answer (score 0):

I just bought a new active Displayport to HDMI adapter and now it is working.